# How to access KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias activity?

Tags: android, key

The following method:[`KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html#choosePrivateKeyAlias(android.app.Activity,%20android.security.KeyChainAliasCallback,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.security.Principal[],%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String)) creates system dialog which allows user to choose a key alias from a list. As one of the arguments it takes Activity context which will be used to spawn this dialog. When selection is made it will call a callback.

In my scenario user doesn't select any alias but presses "Home" button. I would like to intercept this event. How can I do that?

Also I would like to cancel this dialog programatically. In this case I need some way to access this child Activity (please note that `choosePrivateKeyAlias` doesn't return any "handle" to the new dialog). Is it possible to access child Activity without any references (handle/id/etc.) to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to programatically end that activity because it is a system activity. It's the same as launching the browser on your device or the contact list. The only way to exit it is to press back and it will close that activity and resume yours.

Comment: Ok. But what should I do if person presses "Recent Apps" and selects some other activity? In this case I'll not receive any callbacks in my own activity.

Comment: This is true but you will only receive a callback if someone physically selects a key right? And to do that your activity must be active because the dialog is shown in your activity... I've just tested this by performing the KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias call and a dialog is shown... when I press home and I return to my activity the dialog is still visible. Is this not the case on your end?

Comment: I receive a callback when System dialog spawns on top of my activity. After that point I don't receive anything until user closes the dialog. If user switches to another activity I don't receive any notification.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, if you want to dismiss that dialog. Then as far as I know about Android OS. There are lifecycle methods for Activity. So I think

***IF YOU CALL "yourDailog.dismiss()" INSIDE YOUR ACTIVITY's "onStop()". SO YOUR PROBLEM WILL        BE SOLVED***

If you do it in above way, so whenever you press HOME button, It will call onStop method of your activity. At that time, It will dismiss that dialog.

Comment: Please explain what "yourDialog" is? When I spawn the system dialog I don't receive any references to it.

Comment: Please check it

public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean isTrue) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(isTrue);

        if (!isTrue) 
        { 
        Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
            sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
        }
    }

Comment: See that intent part for dismissing system generated dialog

Comment: @VVB I have similar query regarding `chooseAliasPrivateKey`. For my case, I am trying to save that the user have given permission to a specific alias, so that the dialog will only open once and it will never shown to the user as long as they have the app. So I tried to use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45914997/6276898) but when the user hits the back button and opens the app again, my preferences do show that the boolean is saved. But when I try to run the task to retrieve the certificate and privateKey, that task never finishes. Do you have any suggestions on this issue?