# How to prevent choosePrivateKeyAlias dialog in android app?

Tags: android, keychain

I have an android app that call a secured website in a webview.
The webview retrieve the certificate to give it to the website.

I have to use the `KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias(this, keyChainAliasCallback, null, null, null, -1, CERT_ALIAS);` method, and this displays a dialog like this

[image: certificate select]

I'd want to display this window only the first time the user uses the app, but I don't know if it's possible.

I saw about intercepting this with a device/owner profile. Does that mean that it should be on android work ? it's a little blurry to me.

Another solution would be to save certificate and private key retrieve the first time somewhere inaccessible by any other app nor the user. I think about SharedPreferences in private mode.

Am I wrong ?

Thanks for your anwers !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure about the best way to resolve this problem, but here is what I did that worked fine for me.

I checked a boolean variable in the preferences, and if it returns false, I display the `choosePrivateKeyAlias` window. If it returns true, I know that I have permission to retrieve the certificate directly, so there's no need to display the popup.

```
boolean isGranted = prefs.getBoolean("MY_CERT", false);
if(!isGranted) {
        //Get cert and private key from internal android store
        KeyChainAliasCallback keyChainAliasCallback = new KeyChainAliasCallback() {
            @Override
            public void alias(@Nullable String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "selected alias = " + s);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("MY_CERT", true);
                editor.commit();
                retriveCertsTask.execute();
            }
        };
        KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias(mActivity, keyChainAliasCallback, null, null, null, -1, CERT_ALIAS);
    } else {
        // Retrieve certs an private key
        retriveCertsTask.execute();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: what exactly does the retriveCertsTask do ?

Comment: @Ludo How are you handling when user hit the back button to close the app and reopen the app without force closing it. I get stuck at retrieveCertsTask. The task never finishes.

Comment: @philsoady have you faced the issue I mentioned above?

Comment: If the user removes the certificate from the device then this will give a false positive since SharedPreferences wouldn't be updated upon removal of the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following in order to check whether or not the user has already selected the certificate:

```kotlin
activity?.let { it1 ->
    var selectedPrivateKey = KeyChain.getPrivateKey(it1, "keystore-test")
    if (selectedPrivateKey == null) { // if we can't access the private key then prompt for cert selection
        KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias(it1, {
            Log.d("App", "Popped up KeyChain selection screen")
        }, null, null, null, "keystore-test") // this is the alias that is chosen in the popup by default
    }
}
```

`KeyChain.getPrivateKey(it1, "keystore-test")` will return `null` if you don't have access to the private key, meaning that the user did not select a certificate yet.

This implementation will save you from having to use SharedPreferences and also won't give you a false positive if the user deletes the certificate.