# Use Android keystore provider for client authentication

Tags: android, ssl, xamarin.android, ssl-certificate, android-keystore

I have a use case of get a certificate installed in on Android device and send that certificate with the Https request for client authentication with the server. I am using self-signed certificates, so when I install .pfx file it usually end up in user credential. Therefore, to get the certificate from the user store I tried something like this:

```
try
{
    var certs = KeyChain.GetCertificateChain(Context, "Test");

    var pk = KeyChain.GetPrivateKey(Context, "Test");
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

But running the above code gave me an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: uid 10088 doesn't have permission to access the requested alias
```

So after doing some research, I found out that we have to add the below line of code to let users select the certificate from the dialog which is equivalent to giving permission to use the "Test" cert:

```
KeyChain.ChoosePrivateKeyAlias(mainActivity, this, null, null, null, -1, "Test");
```

But for my use case, user shouldn't know about the background activities. So my question: is there any way I can skip the `KeyChain.ChoosePrivateKeyAlias` call and always give permission to use the "Test" cert, so that user don't have to select. Or based on [this article](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore) I have to use Android Keystore provider. But I didn't find any example for Android Keystore provider used for client authentication.

Comment: As I know, the application need to call `ChoosePrivateKeyAlias()` at least once after the application installed. You could try to use a bool value to check if the method called or not so that you do not need to call that every time. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Yes, I know  that `ChoosePrivateKeyAlias()` needs to be called once after the application but do you think there is another way for getting the certificate without going down the `ChoosePrivateKeyAlias()` path.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT can you give an example on how can I use a bool value if the user hits back button to close the app and reopens it without force close. I tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45914997/6276898) using sharedPreference but still not getting certificate if I hit back button and re-open the app again.

Comment: You can skip the Android system keystore and just provide your own keystore with a key loaded from a file or similar.  But I think the prompt is required to allow the app to access the private key.